# Is "in residence" acting as adjective in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me if "in residence" is acting as an adjective in this sentence? Is this similar to when we say "She did an in-residence program"?

"My neighbor's son has to go to rehab," he said.

"Okay," she replied. "In residence?"

"Maybe. We don't know that yet."

Should there be a hyphen with "in residence" here and is it an adjective?

Comment: Doctors are said to be in residence. Patients are hospitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, “in residence” is a prepositional phrase which means: the state of living in a particular place.

> - The flag flies when the Queen is in residence.

In your example: “in residence”

- Is a **short** type of using question; this method is used in speaking, not writing.

In writing, you may write it this way:

> - “is he going to be in residence?”; to live there permanently.

If you hyphenated the phrase, you would radically change the meaning.

See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artist-in-residence)